# Is these angles 90 degrees?

Tags: geometry, triangles

If I have the following triangle:

Where $\angle B=\angle C = O$
And $AP$ bisects $\angle A$ so essentially $\angle BAP = \angle CAP = \frac12 \angle A$
We can prove that $\angle APB = \angle APC$ but how do we show that they are 90 degrees?

$$ \angle APB + \frac12 \angle A + \angle ABC = 180^\circ = \angle ABC + \frac12 \angle A + \angle APC $$

So:

\begin{align}
\angle ABP &= 180^\circ - \left( \angle ABC + \frac12 \angle A \right) \\
\angle APC &= 180^\circ - \left( \angle ABC + \frac12 \angle A \right) \\
\end{align}

So $\angle ABP = \angle APC$ but is it also proven that they are 90 degrees? How?

[image]

Comment: Since BC is a straigth line, $\angle APB + \angle APC = 180$

Comment: @AlainRemillard:Yes but that does not prove that each is 90 degrees right?

Comment: Combine with the fact that $\angle APB = \angle APC$, it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we write a formula for the sum of the angle measures of triangle PAB. I'm going to just use "APB" as "angle APB". We note that angle ABP is "O":
$$O + \frac{A}{2} + APB = 180$$
Next we write a formula for the sum of the angle measures of triangle ABC:
$$2\cdot O + A = 180$$
This gives you that
$$O = \frac{180-A}{2}.$$
We substitue this value for "O" in the formula for triangle PAB:
$$\frac{180-A}{2}+\frac{A}{2} + APB = 180$$
$$90 - \frac{A}{2}+\frac{A}{2}+APB = 180$$
$$90 + APB = 180$$
$$APB = 90.$$

We can do the same thing for APC, using triangle PAC in place of triangle PAB.